# Unable to install HAXM on Windows 10

Tags: android, virtualization

Asking this here because I don't know where else to go, so I recently got a new laptop, moving my Android Studio projects over and whilst I'm installing Android Studio, I'm unable to install HAXM, go into my BIOS, virualization is enabled, check windows, Hyper-V is disabled.

Even disabled the HIVC in Windows Defender and still, unable to install it. It's an 8th gen i7 so I know 100% that it does support vt-x. I just don't know how to fix this. I'm trying to manually install it, and get the message that my computer doesn't support vt-x. So I'm confused.

Sorry if this is the wrong place to post.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but instead, my system will not update to HAXM v7.5.2 (as your post is not that old and you did not state the version you are installing, I thought I'd share my experience here)!  I do have a fix, though (sort of) and, it may work for you.  I know my settings are correct (before I'm "advised" on not knowing my BIOS settings or Windows configuration), because HAXM v7.5.1 works fine (and therein lies my solution).

I first tried updating through Android Studio and got the dreaded *Failed to install Intel HAXM. For details, please check the installation log: "C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\System\haxm-windows_v7_5_2\haxm_silent_run.log"* message.  Since I recently updated my Windows 10 to 1903, I thought that might have been the problem (it's not, as far as I can tell).

My log:

```
=== Logging started: 8/15/2019  11:18:21 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
=== Logging stopped: 8/15/2019  11:18:21 ===
```

I manually downloaded HAXM v7.5.2 and tried to install it from an elevated command prompt - I got the same message.  But, each time I tried, I got a dialog box asking if I wanted to update my currently installed HAXM v7.5.1.

I uninstalled v7.5.1, rebooted, then tried v7.5.2 again - no joy.  I tried all the suggestions I could find online, but still, v7.5.2 would not install.

**My Solution (if HAXM is not working):**

1. Uninstall HAXM (if any are now there)
2. Download [haxm_v7_5_1](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.5.1)
3. Reboot your system
4. Install haxm_v7_5_1 manually (I ran `silent_install.bat` from an elevated command prompt)

I hope this helps!  It works fine for me, though I'd really like to upgrade to v7.5.2!

BTW, if you want to give HAXM more memory (say 2GB), run `silent_install.bat` with the `-m xxxx` option: i.e. `silent_install.bat -m 2048`.